# Configuring windows services using name wildcard

Tags: windows, service, wmi, system

Help needed,

I need to change a state of "Startup Type" of the windows service using one command with a wildcard. I need one command that changes the startup type for all services with name that stating as Citrix*.

I'm already using the following command to stop the services:

`wmic service where "displayname like 'Citrix%'" call StopService`

But I can't find anything that configures the service from commnad line using wildcards.

[image]

Comment: There is a SET command but what should I pass as object? wmic service where "displayname like 'Citrix%'" SET <???>

Answer (score 0):

`wmic service set /?` says ***Writeable properties are not available for this alias or class.***

To set the *Start Mode* property of a windows service, call [`ChangeStartMode` method of the `Win32_Service` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/changestartmode-method-in-class-win32-service). Possible values of the `StartMode` parameter:

> - Boot Start (`Boot`). *Device driver started by the operating system loader. This value is valid only for driver services.*
> - System (`System`). *Device driver started by the operating system initialization process. This value is valid only for driver services.*
> - Auto Start (`Automatic`). *Service to be started automatically by the service control manager during system startup.*
> - Demand Start (`Manual`). *Service to be started by the service control manager when a process calls the StartService method.*
> - Disabled (`Disabled`). *Service that can no longer be started.*

```
==> wmic service call ChangeStartMode /?
Call                    [ In/Out ]Params&type                   Status
====                    =====================                   ======
ChangeStartMode         [IN ]StartMode(STRING)                  (null)
```

**Example** (run in an open elevated `cmd` prompt):

```
wmic service where "displayname like 'Citrix%'" call ChangeStartMode "Manual"
```

Check return value for each service apart (note another `where` clause in the following example):

> ```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32> wmic service where "name like 'Xbl%'" call ChangeStartMode "Manual"
> Executing (\\PC\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Service.Name="XblAuthManager")->ChangeStartMode()
> Method execution successful.
> Out Parameters:
> instance of __PARAMETERS
> {
>         ReturnValue = 0;
> };
>
> Executing (\\PC\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Service.Name="XblGameSave")->ChangeStartMode()
> Method execution successful.
> Out Parameters:
> instance of __PARAMETERS
> {
>         ReturnValue = 0;
> };
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>
> ```